# Date is being converted to Month in SSIS

Tags: date, ssis

I have a text file in which I have date created in british format i.e. '08/01/2014'. I have used derived columns to make sure the format of the date remains the same and using type cast converted to date

```
(DT_DBDATE) (SUBSTRING(VOUCHER_DATE,1,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING(VOUCHER_DATE,4,2) 
                                         + "-" + SUBSTRING(VOUCHER_DATE,7,4))
```

so it should return the date in 08/01/2014 (dd/mm/yyyy) but it is converting it to 01/08/2014. It is converting only the dates less then 10. if date is 11 or 12 or 13 it is doing it fine like 12/01/2014.

see the example in the figure. 9th January is being converted to 1st September and at the same time 22nd January is fine.

```
01/09/2014
01/09/2014
22/01/2014
22/01/2014
22/01/2014
22/01/2014
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you doing wrong, `DT_DBDATE` format is `yyyy-mm-dd` [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141036.aspx).
So it should be:

```
(DT_DBDATE) (SUBSTRING(VOUCHER_DATE,7,4) + "-" + SUBSTRING(VOUCHER_DATE,4,2) + "-" + 
             SUBSTRING(VOUCHER_DATE,1,2))
```

Source:

```
SELECT N'08/01/2014' as VOUCHER_DATE
UNION ALL
SELECT N'01/08/2014'
```

Result:

```
VOUCHER_DATE    Stringtodate
08/01/2014       2014.01.08
01/08/2014       2014.08.01
```

Comment: Hi Justin, I have tried that, no difference. the source file contains this format 08/01/2014

Comment: I made SSIS package and results are in answer, works fine, string converts to date. No difference you say, insert Data Viewer Grid and show picture of data column and converted column.